# Selecting a column value using a fieldname as column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm sure there must be an easier way for me to be doing this, I'm putting myself into a further mess just trying to get my head around how I have set this up!

I have a price lookup table that has 4 different prices based on quantity, so the table layout below shows productID, quantity and then 4 prices (Prices differ by range)

```
product ID  quantity    range 1 range 2 range 3 range 4
1              1         231      265     395     231
1              2         315      345     615     315
1              3         415      485     775     415
```

In another table where the user has selected their product and the chosen quantity I have the name of the chosen range selected in it's own column along with the quantity and product ID

```
product ID  quantity    range name  price
1              2         range 1     xxx <- Needs to be 315
```

I'm trying to perform some kind of UPDATE statement so that I can retrieve and store the price for Range 1 with a Quantity of 2 (£315) in my orderline table but don't know how I can join these two tables together?

I've looked into using the value of the Range Name field as a variable and using EXEC on a SQL statement with the fieldname passed to it but it seems too complex for what I am looking for?

Thanks for looking!

(ADDED EDIT)

-----------EDIT--------------

This is the SQL that I can use to update my price, but the actual name of the field 'range 1' in the SQL below can change, depending on what range the user has selected when choosing...

```
UPDATE tblOrderline
SET price = (SELECT ***'range 1'*** FROM tblPriceLookup WHERE quoteProductID = 1 AND qty = 2)
WHERE orderID = 13 AND quoteProductID = 1
```

-----------END OF EDIT--------------

Comment: can you elaborate in more meaningful way.What you want to achieve???

Comment: If you are in a position to normalize your database design you should do so.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with an `update`/`join` and a `case` statement:

```
update othertable ot join
       pricelookup pl
       on ot.productId = pl.productId and ot.quantity = pl.quantity
    set price = (case when rangename = 'range1' then range1
                      when rangename = 'range2' then range2
                      when rangename = 'range3' then range3
                      when rangename = 'range4' then range4
                 end);
```

EDIT:

I think you still need the `case` stateument:

```
UPDATE tblOrderline ol
    SET price = (SELECT (case when ol.rangename = 'range1' then pl.range1
                              when ol.rangename = 'range2' then pl.range2
                              when ol.rangename = 'range3' then pl.range3
                              when ol.rangename = 'range4' then pl.range4
                         end)
                 FROM tblPriceLookup pl
                 WHERE pl.quoteProductID = 1 AND pl.qty = 2
               )
    WHERE orderID = 13 AND quoteProductID = 1;
```

You should be able to get the same effect by adding a `where` clause to the first query (after adjusting the table and column names).

Comment: Hi Gordon, this looks right to me I'm just having to change some of the syntax as it's not working at the moment.

Can you check my Edit as above to see if this changes your answer?  Regards

Comment: Brilliant Gordon that has worked in my example, I'll now be able to move it into a stored procedure for use on my work.  Regards